# How to Enable startupProbes in Azure Kubernetes Services?

Tags: azure-aks

I understand that this is an experimental feature but one we need. How does one turn this on in Azure Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha features cannot be enabled when using AKS, you would need to look at using AKS-Engine instead which allow you to better control the feature-gate flag for the APIServer: https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/

`Feature    Default Stage   Since`

`StartupProbe   false   Alpha   1.16`

Once a feature hits beta, AKS might consider enabling it I think, depending on the risk and size.

This one seems small.